# WSO2 application instance ID in program environment

Tags: wso2, wso2-as

I am developing an application service based on WSO2 AS. my intention is that the application should be deployed in an AS-cluster in order to cope with the high volume traffic.

the cluster should be a dynamic one in order to scale up or down as per the traffic changes.

also, a user's service might persist in one of the instances for quite some time; in case of failure, a user's service should be restored in a peer instance by the backup and restore mechanism of an object archive(database).

So, the challenge is:

I need to tell the load balancer something about the instance in which the user service persists. so that the load balancer will always route the same user's requests to the same instance in the cluster. and in case of failure, I could update the load balancer with the new instance in which the user's service had been restored.

preferably it could be something that could be generated dynamically by a application server instance; accessible in the program environment; understood and used by the load balancer to route request...

anyone has any idea?

thanks a lot

Comment: Can't you use session replication?

Comment: Hello, Thusitha. thanks for the response, but I have no idea about session replication.  Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: You can read up https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS520/Clustering+and+Http+Session+Replication Session replication is basically your current session is replicated in all other cluster nodes.

Answer (score 0):

After googling around for some time. I found an alternative which WSO2 claimed supporting(http://wso2.com/products/elastic-load-balancer/).

NGinx Plus comes with a feature named Session Persistence (https://www.nginx.com/products/session-persistence/) which provides methods directing load balancer of its routing of incoming requests to a specific back end server